# Selected items don't sum up in total

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got stuck. In the console, each selected item shows up as the `number`, but when I'd like to sum them up by clicking the `#btnCalculate`, the result is always `0`. Only `loan_car` and `casco_v`sum up in total as the `number`. I guess, this mistake is made in the case of `gap_v`, `ns_v` and `tpl_v` could be the `string`. What's the easy way to fix it? Appreciate your value

```js
$(function() {

  $("input[class=input1]").keyup(function() {

    var sum1 = Number($("#carPrice").val());
    var sum2 = Number($("#deposit").val());

    $("#carLoan").val(sum1 - sum2);
  });

  $("#gapList").change(function() {

    var gap_value = $(this).val();
    var gap_result_value = $("#gapListResult").val();
    var $car_cost = $("#carPrice").val();
    var $gap_amount_one = Number(0.010);
    var $gap_amount_two = Number(0.020);
    var $gap_amount_three = Number(0.030);
    var $gap_result_one = function() {
      return Number($car_cost * $gap_amount_one)
    };
    var $gap_result_two = function() {
      return $car_cost * $gap_amount_two
    };
    var $gap_result_three = function() {
      return $car_cost * $gap_amount_three
    };

    if (gap_value == "1") {
      gap_result_value = $gap_result_one();
    } else if (gap_value == "2") {
      gap_result_value = $gap_result_two();
    } else if (gap_value == "3") {
      gap_result_value = $gap_result_three();
    } else {
      gap_result_value = Number(0);
    }
    console.log(gap_result_value);
  }); // works


  $("#nsList").change(function() {

    var ns_value = $(this).val();
    var ns_result_value = $("nsListResult").html();

    if (ns_value == "1") {
      ns_result_value = Number(500);
    } else if (ns_value == "2") {
      ns_result_value = Number(1000);
    } else if (ns_value == "3") {
      ns_result_value = Number(1500);
    } else {
      ns_result_value = Number(0);
    }

    console.log(ns_result_value);

  }); // works


  $("#btnReload").click(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  });

  $("#btnCalculate").click(function() {

    var loan_car = parseFloat($("#carLoan").val()) || 0; // works
    var casco_v = parseFloat($("#costCasco").val()) || 0; // works
    var gap_v = parseFloat($("#gapListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work
    var ns_v = parseFloat($("#nsListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work
    var tpl_v = parseFloat($("#tplListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work

    var loan_sum = loan_car + casco_v + gap_v +
      ns_v + tpl_v;


    $("#totalLoanResult").html(loan_sum);
    console.log(loan_sum);
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="tablet">

    <input type="text" class="input1" id="carPrice"> Sum1
    <input type="text" class="input1" id="deposit"> Sum2
    <input type="text" class="result" style="display:none" id="carLoan">

    <div id="application2">
      <input type="text" class="input2 result" id="costCasco"> Sum3
    </div>

    <select class="dropdown1" id="gapList">
      <option value="0">0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1y</option>
      <option value="2"> 2y</option>
      <option value="3"> 3y</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" class="result" id="gapListResult" style="display:none">


    <select class="dropdown1" id="nsList">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 y</option>
      <option value="2"> 2 y</option>
      <option value="3"> 3 y</option>
    </select>
    <div class="result" style="display:none" id="nsListResult"></div>



    <button type="button" id="btnCalculate"> Calc  </button>

    <button type="button" id="btnReload"> Reload </button>


  </div>

  <div id="totalLoanResult">Result:</div>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX that does not affect the code, it's perfectly valid. On the other hand #nsListResult isn't an input, so you cannot use .val() on it.

Comment: yeah, I see that now, comment removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, gap_result_value and ns_result_value are local variables.

```
$("#gapList").change(function() {
    var gap_value = $(this).val();
    var gap_result_value = $("#gapListResult").val();
    console.log(gap_result_value);
}); // works
```

You can not use gap_result_value in other places. That is why you see the corect number in console.

Second if you change the value of gap_result_value, this change wont affect #gapListResult;

```
$("#btnCalculate").click(function() {
    var gap_v = parseFloat($("#gapListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work

    var loan_sum = loan_car + casco_v + gap_v +ns_v + tpl_v;

    $("#totalLoanResult").html(loan_sum);
});
```

That is why is not working. #gapListResult has no value

Try this:
Insert  $("#gapListResult").val(gap_result_value); inside $("#gapList").change(function() {} at the end.
Insert $("#nsListResult").val(ns_result_value); inside $("#nsList").change(function() {}
at the end.

And also you are mising a # here : var ns_result_value = $("nsListResult").html();

```js
$(function() {

  $("input[class=input1]").keyup(function() {

    var sum1 = Number($("#carPrice").val());
    var sum2 = Number($("#deposit").val());

    $("#carLoan").val(sum1 - sum2);
  });

  $("#gapList").change(function() {

    var gap_value = $(this).val();
    var gap_result_value = $("#gapListResult").val();
    var $car_cost = $("#carPrice").val();
    var $gap_amount_one = Number(0.010);
    var $gap_amount_two = Number(0.020);
    var $gap_amount_three = Number(0.030);
    var $gap_result_one = function() {
      return Number($car_cost * $gap_amount_one)
    };
    var $gap_result_two = function() {
      return $car_cost * $gap_amount_two
    };
    var $gap_result_three = function() {
      return $car_cost * $gap_amount_three
    };

    if (gap_value == "1") {
      gap_result_value = $gap_result_one();
    } else if (gap_value == "2") {
      gap_result_value = $gap_result_two();
    } else if (gap_value == "3") {
      gap_result_value = $gap_result_three();
    } else {
      gap_result_value = Number(0);
    }
    console.log(gap_result_value);
    $("#gapListResult").val(gap_result_value); //******
  }); // works


  $("#nsList").change(function() {

    var ns_value = $(this).val();
    var ns_result_value = $("#nsListResult").html(); //******

    if (ns_value == "1") {
      ns_result_value = Number(500);
    } else if (ns_value == "2") {
      ns_result_value = Number(1000);
    } else if (ns_value == "3") {
      ns_result_value = Number(1500);
    } else {
      ns_result_value = Number(0);
    }

    console.log(ns_result_value);
    $("#nsListResult").val(ns_result_value); //******
  }); // works


  $("#btnReload").click(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  });

  $("#btnCalculate").click(function() {

    var loan_car = parseFloat($("#carLoan").val()) || 0; // works
    var casco_v = parseFloat($("#costCasco").val()) || 0; // works
    var gap_v = parseFloat($("#gapListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work
    var ns_v = parseFloat($("#nsListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work
    var tpl_v = parseFloat($("#tplListResult").val()) || 0; // doesn't work

    var loan_sum = loan_car + casco_v + gap_v +
      ns_v + tpl_v;


    $("#totalLoanResult").html(loan_sum);
    console.log(loan_sum);
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="tablet">

    <input type="text" class="input1" id="carPrice"> Sum1
    <input type="text" class="input1" id="deposit"> Sum2
    <input type="text" class="result" style="display:none" id="carLoan">

    <div id="application2">
      <input type="text" class="input2 result" id="costCasco"> Sum3
    </div>

    <select class="dropdown1" id="gapList">
      <option value="0">0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1y</option>
      <option value="2"> 2y</option>
      <option value="3"> 3y</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" class="result" id="gapListResult" style="display:none">


    <select class="dropdown1" id="nsList">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 y</option>
      <option value="2"> 2 y</option>
      <option value="3"> 3 y</option>
    </select>
    <div class="result" style="display:none" id="nsListResult"></div>



    <button type="button" id="btnCalculate"> Calc  </button>

    <button type="button" id="btnReload"> Reload </button>


  </div>

  <div id="totalLoanResult">Result:</div>
```

Comment: You're outuput looks a bit messed up

Comment: I only inserted 2 lines of code in the original: $("#gapListResult").val(gap_result_value); and  $("#nsListResult").val(ns_result_value); and an "#". Nothing else.

Comment: yeah but this messed it up somehow:). Compare your run code snippet and the one of OP

Comment: Fixed it. Now it looks pretty again :)

Comment: @DanielNuevo you have so many open question please start to accept answers if people helped you.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#nsListResult").val()` this is a hidden input field with empty text.

If you parse and empty String you'll get NaN

Try this instead

```
$("#nsListResult").val(); //returns NaN (Not a Number) if you parse it to float because $("#nsListResult").val() returns ""

// try this on the values which are not working:
!isNaN(parseFloat($("#nsListResult").val())) ? parseFloat($("#nsListResult").val()) : 0
```

so if the parse operation is a number return that number else return 0